# Editing values in Excel

Tags: excel, function

```
       COL1         COL2
   (1432)UE           UE
(1352)XE234        XE234
         AA           AA
   (512) GT           GT
 (412)XT I3        XT I3
```

I have a column like COL1. I need to delete the (*) values to create COL2. How can I do this in Excel? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data starts in `A1`, this formula will do the job:

```
=IF(OR(ISERROR(SEARCH("(",A1)),ISERROR(SEARCH(")",A1))),A1,TRIM(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(")",A1))))
```